# Errors were encountered while processing: python-pexpect

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, python, dpkg

After normal periodic upgrade, I got

*`After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.`*

*`Setting up python-pexpect (4.0.1-0~ppatrusty2) ...`*

`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/async.py", line 16`

`transport, pw = yield from asyncio.get_event_loop()\`

`.                        ^`

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
`dpkg: error processing package python-pexpect (--configure):`
 `subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 101`
`Errors were encountered while processing:`
`python-pexpect`
`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

How do i fix this??

Answer (score 5):

Take a look here [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-make/+bug/1507871).

While they are solving the problem, you can downgrade the package using:

```
apt-get install python-pexpect/trusty python3-pexpect/trusty
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying to find a clean solution, in the end, just remove the `python-pexpect` package and run `autoremove` so far nothing seems broken.